# How to update plugins version (of a rails project) when old version had manual changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

How to update many plugins version when old plugin's version had manual changes in project?

Is there any tool available for doing this?

or tell proper method for updating ruby plugin version if some plugins may have manual changes  done before in the older plugin's version.

Comment: looks like the only way to update them is to make a backup of the changes, then update plugins just as usual, and then merge the versions manually. Actually it would be nice to see the diffs from the original plugin with the old version first, to find out what to look for. Not convenient, but modifying the plugins code was never a good idea

Comment: I agree! This is a project I have for maintenance. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best method when a plugin is required or preferred *might be to copy out the old plugin to a dummy directory for reviewing later, then

uninstall the plugin, (script/plugin uninstall plugin_name)

install the old (but unmodified version) plugin (script/plugin install plugin_name_source_address) - likely either from rubyforge or github

review against the saved version you put in the dummy directory using an editor capable of differential display (that is, which allows you to compare two files for variations. Notepad++ is one freebie that will do this, but there are a ton of editors that allow diff views)

*(this may or may not be something you can script. idk. I'm not that good, but I don't know of a tool that will do it all for you)*

do another uninstall on the plugin to clear it out, since it's job is done,

install the new version of the plugin (script/plugin install plugin_name_source_address)

and finally edit the new plugin *as necessary* to accommodate any customization that was performed by you or some third party to the original utility.

I say as necessary because some of the customizations may not even be required in the newer version, although I can't say for sure...

finally, once all your patches are re-added to the new plugin and it's been tested and verified, either delete the dummy directory or archive it for future reference.

See, and I didn't even cop out with a bundler answer. You DID ask for assistance with a **plugin**, right? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite following you, but surely but that's what the `Gemfile` is for?

Take a look at [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

Comment: Well lebreeze, My question is related with manual changes was done inside of plugin installed..

Answer (score 0):

Try to run "`$gem install rails`"(it will install the newer version of rails) and then install watever the gem it asks finally run "`$bundle install`"

Comment: My question is related with manual changes was done inside of plugin installed and not gems at all.

Comment: can u specify the name of the plugin?

Comment: There are 8 plugins but changes are possible in `will_paginate` and some others too. actually changes are not done by me but by other companies. They are telling me to check if any changes are in plugin and copy changes from older version to the new version accordingly.

Comment: only thing u can do is set ur app config to the legacy plugin.